# Channels and memory configuration in a new PC build

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, cpu-cooler

I'm a newbie and recently got to build my first PC.

Bought two SINGLE Ram sticks, DDR4 1x8gb ballistix 2666mhz 1.2V

Motherboard has 2 dual configuration channels, Channel A uses slots 2 and 4, Channel B uses slots 1 and 3.

The CPU cooler is wide, and I can't fit the memory modules into socket 4.

May I use channel B, while ignoring channel A without consequences? May I put the memory randomly because they arent suit for dual channel config?

Comment: It may be helpful, especially for other issues, to specify the make and model of your motherboard. To do so, click [edit] and enhance the original post. It's far better to expand on your original question in the question so all may see all of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Fill 1 & 2

Will work in dual channel mode then.

Most boards that I know have channel A = slot 1 + 2 and B = slot 3 + 4
There filling 1 & 3 would result in dual channel mode.

Oftenly each pair of slots on the board has its color so use same color slots.

In most scenarios a 4 core with dual channel RAM access will be faster than an overclocked 32 core with single channel RAM access.